# Jvector maps with integration of mysql data

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, maps

I am using Jvector maps. I have the html code to display the map as well as js files with the necessary code to help me see the country name when I hover on a country. I am very new to this and I need to get this done soon. So could someone provide me details with how I can display names of users (stored in mysql database) who belong to the respective country when I hover over that country.

Comment: What have you done so far? Post your code and then point to an area you're having difficulty in

Comment: You could write a web service and then call it on hover event of the country map. This WS will then fetch the users from database and return a JSON response matching to your criteria.